# How to notify when childwindow appear

Tags: silverlight-4.0

At my application i would like to monit when childwindow appear. I could use some event in childwindow, but i preffer some more generic solution, one function which will be invoke when childwindow is opening...

Something like

Application.Current.RootVisual.ChildWindowOpened - but unfortunetly not such even in silverlight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ChildWindow must be manually invoked, you could create a helper method like this:

```
public void OpenChildWindow()
{
    ChildWindow1 CW = new ChildWindow1();
    CW.Show();
    if (ChildWindowOpened != null)
        ChildWindowOpened(this, null);
}

public event EventHandler ChildWindowOpened;
```